# How to compare different groups with different sample size?

Tags: statistics, data-science, line-plot, sample-size

[image]I am plotting students' data from different schools to see the difference between male and female student numbers at some majors. I am using python, I already plot the data for some schools and as I expected male numbers are genuinely higher, then I realized that for each school I have a different number of total students. does my work make any sense when the sample size is different? if not may I have some suggestion to make some changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I'm realizing.
 Look: you have two classes where the first has 2 men, the second one - 20 men. And their marks. 2 men - both are 90/100. And 20 marks in the second one. Let it be a range from 40 to 80. Will it be correct if we say "Well, the first class made the test much better then the second"? Ofc, not. 
To solve this problem just take a `min(sizes of samples)`. If it looks too small, so throw away this programm, because you have not enough data to say something. And put a total size of sample via proxy legend or text, or add it in title. Anyway it will show you reliability of your results.

Comment: **UPD**. By "programm" I meant  major programm, not your code

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about programming, but rather about statistics, but I will try to answer. 
Important question I didn't get there: What are you doing it for? If you ask question like *"Hmm... Are there more men than women in the population(in this case, population = all persons in major programm)?"*. So each schools aren't important for you,and you can work with samples as you work with one (but don't forger gather them).

But you may ask question: "are there any difference between schools in samples?". In this case, gathering is not correct. For this purpose I highly recommend barh plot with `stucked=True` for each school. And for normalization just use percents. And difference between samples' size won't be problem.

**PLS, If you ask question, put some code. 3 rows and one plot from a sample would be very helpful...**

Comment: It is more about statistics, thank you for answering my question. I want to know the gender gap among majors at different academic levels. Like in Junior college/undergraduate/graduate. I added a plot.